# AWS SageMaker MXNet USE_CUDA=1

Tags: machine-learning, nvidia, amazon-sagemaker, mxnet

I am using the AWS ml.p2.xlarge sagemaker instance and conda_amazonei_mxnet_p36 kernel after install MXnet CUDA

```
!pip install mxnet-cu101
```

when I try to run the following code

```
mx_tfidf = mx.nd.sparse.array(tfidf_matrix, ctx=mx.gpu())
```

I am getting the following error

```
MXNetError: [19:54:53] src/storage/storage.cc:119: 
Compile with USE_CUDA=1 to enable GPU usage
```

Please help me to resolve the issue

```
nvidia-smi
```

[image: nvidia configuration as follows]

Answer (score 1):

please consider using the other Jupyter kernels `conda_mxnet_p27` or `conda_mxnet_p36`. The kernel you use - `conda_amazonei_mxnet_p36` - is primarily designed for local testing of the [Amazon Elastic Inference](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/elastic-inference/) hardware accelerator, (exposed as `mx.eia()` hardware context in mxnet), and presumably doesn't come with the `mx.gpu()` context enabled.